# position:fixed but with margin?

Tags: jquery, css

I have some buttons which are fixed either side of my page, they work well however if the browser window is made smaller (or the user has a very small resolution), the buttons fall bellow the footer.

I've seen it done before, an element is fixed to the side of the page but when you scroll to the bottom they are pushed up do avoid overflow.

Maybe its more than CSS?

Many thanks,

Jake

**Edit:**
For those interested here is an example of the solution:
http://blog.echoenduring.com/wp-content/uploads/demos/echo_ContainedStickyScroll/

Comment: can you append your source code ?

Comment: Sounds like something you would do with jQuery, unless you can just use z-index to float the arrows above the footer so they are still visible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery Plugin [StickyScroll](http://www.orangecoat.com/stickyscroll) may be what you're looking for — a jQuery plugin for creating elements that 'stick' to the top of the window when scrolling down the page.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
.button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

This would keep a button always 10px above the ground. If you want to dynamically slide up the button each time the user scrolls down with some nice effects, you will have to use javascript.

Comment: Well that's a possibility, although there would be the same issue I think, except it would overflow past the header! I think I might need to use jQuery, maybe even one with a nice bouncy effect - anyone know of such a script?